# Selenium Grid tests will only run once

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-grid

I have a virtual machine that I am using as a Selenium Grid Hub and Node.

Hub set up is run via a bat file as follows;

```
cd c:\Automated Tests\Selenium\
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.0.jar -role hub -hubhost 'my.ip.address' -port 4444
```

The node set up is run via a bat file as follows;

```
cd c:\Automated Tests\Selenium\
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.0.jar -port 5555 -role node -nodehost 'my.ip.address' hub http://'my.ip.address'/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,version=32.0.1,platform=WINDOWS" -nodeTimeout 600
```

I have a simple c# test that will do a quick search on google then close the browser as follows;

```
    [Test]
    public void Main()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "32.0.1");
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WINDOWS");

        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://my.ip.address:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

        ISelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rAgXVJmiKeLL8gflvoGgAw");
        selenium.Start();

        selenium.Open("/");
        selenium.SelectWindow("null");
        selenium.Type("id=gbqfq", "Test");
        selenium.Click("id=gbqfb");

        driver.Close();
```

When I run the test in visual studio, the test will successfully run and pass as expected, however, if I run the test a second time, I always get a timeout and the test always fails.

Messages;
OpenQA.Selenium.WebdriverException : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL HTTP://'my.ip.address'/wd/hub/session timed out after 60 seconds. ----> System.Net

Following a link in the message gets me a further message of;

HTTP ERROR: 500

Problem accessing /wd/hub/session. Reason:

org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Cannot extract a capabilities from the request

Im quite new to coding and Selenium grid, and dont understand why the test will not run more than once.  Any help with this query will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found that I was not disposing of my sessions at the end of the test.  Once I had done this I was able to run my test multiple times without issue.

```
    [Test]
    public void Main()
    {

        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "32.0.1");
        capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "WINDOWS");


        IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://10.222.4.69:4444/wd/hub"), capability);

        ISelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=rAgXVJmiKeLL8gflvoGgAw");
        selenium.Start();

        selenium.Open("/");
        selenium.SelectWindow("null");
        selenium.Type("id=gbqfq", "Test");
        selenium.Click("id=gbqfb");

        driver.Close();
        driver.Quit();//added this
        driver.Dispose();//added this
```